# Genymotion application for iOS

Tags: ios, automation, appium, genymotion

Is there an application similar to genymotion for ios ? Also could genymotion be hooked on to appium ? I have been using genymotion for android but in search of a fast emulator for ios as well.

Comment: The emulator on mac is fast enough. Also I don't thing there is something like that.

Comment: but i want to test ios application on windows

Comment: Yes you can test iOS application on windows (sort of). I installed Mac OS on VirtualBox and then deploy to it using Visual Studio remote build. It works.

Answer (score 13):

No, there is not.

The only way to run an iOS app is in a simulator on a Mac that is shipped with Xcode or on an actual device. This is a restriction enforced by Apple developer license.